# What repeated measures statistical tests should I use with uneven sample size and parametrical/nonparametrical distribution?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, nonparametric, heterogeneity, parametric

I'm looking for a way to measure significance + variance homogeneity/heterogenity
First of all I tested my data for normality and it's not always parametrical, so I think that I should use different tests for parametrical/nonparametrical data (fig 1 and 2).
As I understood I can't use repeated measures ANOVA if I have unequal sample size so any tips would be highly apprecitated[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide more information about, what is your research question? how does your variables look like?

Comment: @Kirsten hi, I'm measuring rat locomotor activity for example how many sectors during the test were crossed, or how many times center sector was crossed https://imgur.com/a/Z2EJL9y https://imgur.com/a/cYzbO6V